# Как привести объект типа Collision к более конкретному?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Допустим есть некий GameObject под названием Cube на котором висит скрипт:

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float HP = 10f;
}
```

Я хочу изменить значение поля HP при столкновении объекта Cube с Cubik (скрипт Cubik:

```
public class Cubik : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Cube")
        {
            collision.HP --;
        }
    }
}
```

)

Как привести тип collision  к типу Cube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<BulletControll>();
```

и почему у вас скрипт называется Cubik а класс BulletControll? Разве названия не должны совпадать?

Comment: Я копировал из скрипта и не переименовал. Названия для нейтральности подобрал.